# Datagrid Blank Row's Row Number

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row-number

I have a WPF Datagrid and I am populating the row numbers for it on the LoadingRow Event:

```
    private void GridAccounts_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
    }
```

It seems that doing this, the blank, new row that shows up at the end of the datagrid shows the incorrect row number until the user clicks into that row.  After the user clicks into the row, the LoadingRow event is fired and the correct row number is displayed.  Is there a way to show the correct row number before the user clicks into the row?  Below is an example image of my error:

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the right number. Either way, this is the `NewItemPlaceholder`, i would just leave it blank, you have the row with that placeholder when `e.Row.DataContext == CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder` evaluates to `true`, so you could just do nothing in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I confused myself for a bit there.  Since the datagrid gets loaded right away, it was assigning the blank row a number before the user adds data to it.  I am now checking if the DataContext equals NewItemPlaceholder and get the expected results I was hoping for.